# ASP.NET Core 6 CORS and Angular 14 problem with published mode

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, cors, webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 project which client side is angular 14 .
I had enable CORS as code below :

```
  var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    var  MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";


builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.WithOrigins("https://consultation.programmerbox.ir",
                                              "http://localhost:4200")
                                                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                                                  .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

when i call the api with **postman** -> **api return value as well as possible**, when i call api in client project(**development localhost**) -> **api return value as well as possible** , **but** when publish both client and backend code in diffrent domain i get this **error** :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.consultation.programmerbox.ir/api/account/sendVerificationCode' from origin 'https://consultation.programmerbox.ir' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

client domain is : https://consultation.programmerbox.ir
and backend domain is  : https://api.consultation.programmerbox.ir/

I would be very grateful if you could guide me in this field, I am new in this field
With best regards

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Hoh.png)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4dtF.png)

Comment: In the network tab of browser, does it fire the request and show CORS error there as well. At times, the CORS error will be shown in console but actual cause is something else

Comment: Just so there's no mistake:  The code above which enables CORS is for the server hosting `api.consultation.programmerbox.ir`?

Comment: @possum yes , these codes are for api (server) , i dont undrestand where is the problem :-(

Comment: @possum when i publish both client and backend in same domain , there is no problem , but different domain or different subdomain makes error :-(